# Property 'category' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object & { children?: ReactNode }

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I was trying to render a form on Next.js using Formik & typescript but I keep getting:
`Property 'category' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object & { children?: ReactNode }`

This is the code that renders error:

```
     auto: () => {
        return (
          <AutoLeadForm
            category="auto"
            loading={isLoading}
            submitHandler={leadFormHandler}
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            buttonVariant={buttonVariant}
            showRandomCounter={showRandomCounter}
            classNameField={classNameField}
            classNameButton={classNameButton}
            isPopup={isPopup}
            isInArticle={isInArticle}
            randomCounter={randomCounter}
          />
        );
      }
```

And this is the props passing:

```
const AutoLeadForm = (props: AutoLeadFormProps & FormikProps<FormValues>) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    category,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
    loading,
    showRandomCounter,
    classNameField,
    classNameButton,
    isPopup = false,
    isInArticle = false,
    randomCounter,
  } = props;
```

I can ensure you that I have passed the props correctly, because the form can be rendered and the submit works, but the build keeps showing that error, anybody knows why?

Comment: Can you also share the definition of `AutoLeadFormProps`?

Comment: Also, the generic type `FormValues` is not being set on `AutoLeadForm` so are we missing some code here? Which exact line is showing the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears that you have something like type `AutoLeadFormProps = object` instead of an actual type like `type AutoLeadFormProps = { category: string }`.  The `object` type is essentially useless as it doesn’t define any properties.